# AnimatedView rotate transform when position is absolute

Tags: react-native

I have two animated views in a react native component. I want to rotate the second one with the rotation transform. The rotation works but I don't want my views to cross each other on the middle. **I want them to start from the same origin on the left... Like a clock.**

Any idea how I could do this in an elegent way(without hardcoding everything each time)?

I use the absolute positioning because I want them to start from the same place. If you have any other creative alternative please tell me.
**It needs to stay at the same origin even if I animate the width...**

Thanks

```
<Animated.View style={{
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    width: 120,
    height: 26,
    borderRadius: 13,
    position: 'absolute'
}} />
<Animated.View style={{
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    width: 120 // an increasing animated value for the width here in the real app
    height: 26,
    borderRadius: 13,
    position: 'absolute',
    transform: [{
    rotate: '160deg'
    }]
}} />
```

Here is what it looks like so far:

[image]